# How can I get the actual value into an hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using the Iconselect and I wanted to ask how I can transmit the actual and/or selected value into an hidden field - I can't find a solution :(

```
<input type="hidden" id="recommandation" name="recommandation" value="" />
...
<script>
 var iconSelect;
 window.onload = function(){
    iconSelect = new IconSelect("my-icon-select", 
        {'selectedIconWidth':24,
        'selectedIconHeight':24,
        'selectedBoxPadding':1,
        'iconsWidth':20,
        'iconsHeight':20,
        'boxIconSpace':1,
        'vectoralIconNumber':4,
        'horizontalIconNumber':4});
    var icons = [];
    icons.push({'iconFilePath':'/images/sampledata/eval-1.jpg', 'iconValue':'1'});
    icons.push({'iconFilePath':'/images/sampledata/eval-2.jpg', 'iconValue':'2'});
    icons.push({'iconFilePath':'/images/sampledata/eval-3.jpg', 'iconValue':'3'});
    iconSelect.refresh(icons);
 };
</script>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In taking a quick look at IconSelect, it appears you could do something like:

```
$('#my-icon-select').on('changed', function(){
    $('#recommandation').val(iconSelect.getSelectedValue());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("id-of-selector").on('blur', function(){
    $('#recommandation').val = this.val;
});
```

or

```
var element =  document.getElementById('id-of-selector')
element.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
    document.getElementById('recommandation').value = element.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about iconselect never used it but manipulating the value with jquery it does not matter if it is hidden look at this:

http://api.jquery.com/val/